# Force a traceroute to go through added IP address

Tags: linux, debian, routing, ip

Currently speaking I am on a linux (debain) machine which has 2 routed public IPv4 address:

- 1.1.1.50
- 1.1.1.60

Both of these IP addresses are currently simply added as a vitual host:

- 1.1.1.50 -> eth0
- 1.1.1.60 -> eth0:0

If I currently do a traceroute to either it will show something like:

```
5) ...
6) 2.2.2.2 (upstream IP address)
7) 1.1.1.50
```

or

```
5) ...
6) 2.2.2.2 (upstream IP address)
7) 1.1.1.60
```

However what I want to achieve is when a external user tries to traceroute 1.1.1.60 to display it going through 1.1.1.50

so the end result should look like:

```
5) ...
6) 2.2.2.2 (upstream IP address)
7) 1.1.1.50
8) 1.1.1.60
```

How do I go about achieving this? Is this something I can do using IPTABLES or the ip command? and if so how?

Comment: I might very well be wrong, but: packets to the .60 ip-address are **not** routed via the .50 ip-address so of course that ip-address won't be in any traceroute. If you were to change the ip-address of your eth0 device (for instance to 127.1.1.)  but don't change the ip-address of eth0:0 packets would still arrive...

Answer (score 0):

This'll not work because this is just an IP alias (the interface does not really exist). Anyway, you would need a specific route for 1.1.1.60 on your router, but I am assuming this IS the same machine. I'd personally go for a virtual interface like this:

```
ip tuntap add dev eth7 mode tap
ifconfig eth7 1.1.1.60 netmask 255.255.255.255
ifconfig up
```

And setting the routing accordingly.

I hope this helps.

Comment: the whole /24 is routed on the router to the machine (eth0)
I also currently have ipv4 forwarding in my sysctl enabled

I tried adding the tuntap interface and adding the new IP as a /32 as per your instructions but seems that even then and applying the static route to the dev eth0 it still goes direct to 1.1.1.60 instead of going through 1.1.1.50

Comment: By setting the route accordingly I meant on 2.2.2.2. Unless you don't control it.

Comment: Sadly I do not control the 2.2.2.2 upstream routes.
The upstream simply pushes the full 1.1.1.0/24 to my linux box on 1 NIC,

Comment: Well 2.2.2.2 will send packets to 1.1.1.60 according to two things: its routing table and its ARP table. And these clearly indicate that 1.1.1.60 is reachable directly. You could try something like ICMP redirect, or some complicated IP mangling... but that is far beyond my knowledge.